# Saving during a mission on w40k:DoW2?

Tags: warhammer-40k-dawn-of-war-ii

I've bought this game a year ago or so and just now I had the time to play it.
There is a problem, though. Is there a mod, a patch...even a virus...that allows me to save during a mission in the campaign mode?
My necessity it's not to cheat or to restart a mission, it's just that sometimes I have to go out for some reason and I lost a mission just because I can't save. It's really annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply cannot as it would be easy to abuse the campaign system with that.  It is just a game design choice the designers made.

Comment: I get it could be easy to abuse but it does not change the fact that is annoying.

Comment: What I do is I just don't close the game if I got to do something else.